# how to improve cache use in mysql when query

Tags: mysql, performance, caching

when I improve the efficiency by using the query as follows:

```
 select retweet_id from mysqlQ3 where user_id ='99963947’;
```

When I googled , I found that I can change the following parameters:

```
query_cache_type=2
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_size=32M
```

But I am curious that when I change query_cache_type from 1 to 2, it even had bad performance for throughput. What happened? Could anyone specify how to improve mysql performance for this specific query like above?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an index for the column user_id, From the manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> - To find the rows matching a WHERE clause quickly.

Comment: yes， I have already used it, but for so many queries like that to my table, I don't know how to improve query throughput. when I changed query_cache_type from 1 to 2, it's throughput even smaller. Do you know why is that? how to optimize cache so as to improve query throughput? FYI, my table stores about 500 M data.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am curious that when I change query_cache_type from 1 to 2, it even had bad performance for throughput. What happened?

I think your answer is actually in the MySQL documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html

- A value of 0 or OFF prevents caching or retrieval of cached results.
- A value of 1 or ON enables caching except of those statements that begin with SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE.
- A value of 2 or DEMAND causes caching of only those statements that begin with SELECT SQL_CACHE.

So, a value of 2 is much more restrictive in what is cached than a value of 1, and will only hit the cache if explicitly requested by the caller, otherwise will not cache.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an INDEX on `id`?  Probably you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, which is even better.  In that case, don't bother with the Query cache.

Do you have a lot of writes to that table?  Each time a write occurs, *all* entries in the QC for *that* table are purged.  This means scanning the 32M looking for any entries for that table.  The scan is costly and you are left with nothing like that query in the QC.

Back to `id` being indexed...  For a MyISAM table, `key_buffer_size` should be tuned to perhaps 20% of available RAM.  For a InnoDB table, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of available RAM.  Those are the engine-specific caches; they are not purged by a write, hence they are more reliable for point-queries like the one mentioned.

In almost all "production" servers I have dealt with, the QC is, or should be, turned off.